# What minimizing challenges arise for functions which are not convex?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to figure out why functions that are convex (convex everywhere) are easier to minimize than functions that are NOT convex everywhere.

My main theory was that non-convex functions have multiple extrema (local minima and maxima) and thus the algorithm could get "trapped" in one of those local minimums.

However, I then came up with a function that is not convex yet has only one minimum:

[image]
Sorry for the horrible drawings! I dont know the equation for this function.

As you can see, this function has regions of convexity and concavity (2nd derivative > 0 and <0, respectively), yet only one extrema.

So why would this function I drew be harder to minimize than just a normal, "non-wavy" parabola?

EDIT: A commenter pointed out that my function $f(x)$ is quasiconvex which means maybe my initial theory about multiple extrema being the major challenge is true for all non-convex AND non-quasiconvex functions.

Comment: Slightly tangential comment, but the function on the left appears to be quasiconvex, meaning that its sublevel sets are all convex. And quasiconvex functions can be minimized easily, as a rule of thumb, using convex optimization (a way to do this is explained in Boyd and Vandenberghe).

Comment: One nice thing about a convex function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is that, if you evaluate $\nabla f(x)$, then you know that $f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y - x \rangle$ for all $y \in \mathbb R^n$. That seems helpful if we're trying to minimize $f$. (I'm assuming $f$ is differentiable. If $f$ is not differentiable, we could use a subgradient of $f$ at $x$ in place of $\nabla f(x)$.)